# How do i read a .txt line by line in C?

Tags: c, string, file

I've read everything about this and still i haven't figured out how to do this. I'm trying to read a .txt line by line and put that in an array. I think my code kinda works but when i try to print the array it doesn't let me.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
int main(){
    char s[20],*list[196][20];
    int i;
    FILE *lista;
    lista=fopen("lista.txt","r");
    i=0;
    while(feof==0){
        getline(list[i],0,lista);
        i=i+1;
        printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<195;i++){
        //printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    }
    fclose(lista);
}
```

Reason why is there 2 prints is because i tried both ways to see if i could fix it.
Any idea on what am i doing wrong?
The error i get is "format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'char**'

Comment: We need your definition of `getline`. Ah.. I see. Linux non-standard library extension. About identical to `fgets` except for the optional memory allocation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie [`geline()` is POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is your reason to *declare list as array 196 of array 20 of pointer to char*? The code seems more reliable.

```
int main ( void )
{
   static const char filename[] = "lista.txt";
   FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
   char list[196][20];
   int i = 0;
   if ( file != NULL )
   {
      char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
      while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
      {
         strcpy( list[i], line );  /* copy the line into list */
         fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
         ++i;
      }
      fclose ( file );
   }
   else
   {
      perror ( filename ); /* why didn't the file open? */
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! your code works. Altough, when i print the array it prints two times, i don't know what's up with that.

Comment: I used an array [196][20] because my .txt has 196 words. I used *list because getline needed it

Comment: When you want it as pointer, you have to hold some place to put your stuff in it. So, no space has been allocated. I don't know why it prints twice however likely about implementation of getline function. En passant, if an answer helps you, you should accept it by clicking the tique.

Answer (score 0):

[`getline()` is a standard POSIX function.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html)

There are several problems with your code.

First, you're using `getline()` wrong.  By passing the address of your fixed-size array element and zero as its size, `getline()` will likely try to `realloc()` your pointer, and that won't work.

This will work, as long as there are enough lines in the file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
int main(){
    char *list[196];
    size_t bytes[196];

    FILE *lista;
    lista=fopen("lista.txt","r");
    if ( null == lista )
    {
        return( -1 );
    }

    // while(feof==0) is *so* wrong...
    for ( int i = 0; i < 196; i++){
        list[i] = NULL;
        bytes[i] = 0;
        // note that the address of list[i] and bytes[i] are
        // passed - if you examine them after the call, you'll
        // see they changed value.  Since C is pass-by-value,
        // the address must be passed to allow the variable in
        // main to be modified by the getline() call
        ssize_t bytes_read = getline(&list[i],&bytes[i],lista);
        if ( bytes_read <= 0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    }

    fclose(lista);
    return(0);
}
```

And `while(feof==0)` is wrong on many levels. The bare `feof` evaluates to the *address* of the `feof()` function, and that will never be equal to zero.  Assuming you meant `while (feof(lista)==0)`, that's wrong, too.  See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for why.

Answer (score -1):

With Your approach try sth like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINES_NO 4096
int main(){
    char *list[MAX_LINES_NO];
    int i = 0;
    FILE *lista;
    lista=fopen("lista.txt","r");
    size_t len = 0;
    for(i=0; i< MAX_LINES_NO; ++i) list[i] = 0;
    i=0;
    while(-1 != getline(&list[i],&len,lista)){
    printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    ++i;
}

    for(i=0; i< MAX_LINES_NO; ++i) free(list[i]);

fclose(lista);
}
```

In this approach You can change MAX_LINES_NO to dynamicaly allocate array of pointers. Note that this approach rely on getline specific behaviour when buffer and len is 0, (it dynamically allocates memory: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html).

Comment: That prints one line and segfaults. Did you check it before posting?

Comment: Yes, where are You getting segfault?

Comment: Tried your code but i get "segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

Comment: Line 14 (the `while` condition). The pointer given to `getline` needs to be a valid address or `NULL`. And if have done so you need to check the `free` loop fro bounds or it will segfault there, too.

Comment: You must set `len` to zero before calling `getline` for it to allocate the buffer. That's why it now segfaults! This is not a good solution.

Comment: No that was not a problem i didn't set i to 0 before while thats all.

Comment: From the manual: "_If *lineptr is set to NULL and __*n is set 0__ before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer [...]_"